# Using map from ArcGIS Server in radMap?

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-server, c#, wpf

I was wondering if there was a way to use a map that I have stored on an ArcGIS Server in a telerik radMap. I am not very familiar with the radMap control. I have found the documentation on using a radMap with Shapefiles, but it was not very helpful.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation only Bing and OpenStreetMap are supported:  http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radmap-overview.html

However, it appears that a custom provider can be created to use ArcGIS Server map service.

http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radmap-howto-custom-provider.html

So if you are using a cached service then you would want to create a TileProvider and if you are using a dynamic map service then you should want to create an ImageProvider.

The only other option it seems is to export your data as a shapefile or KML file and load that in the control.

## Added

It appears that a UriImageProvider is provided that may work, but I do not know how the request is sent to the server for the bounding box, but you could point it the map service and include the export to png and it may work.

```
http://arcgis/service/mapserver/export?format=png
```

Comment: So whenever I used arcGIS I was able to get access to my maps through http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CalvertCity_Test_Labels/MapServer/0 that URL... I just don't understand how I would use that URL based on their documentation.

Comment: So in the custom provider you want to override the initialize method and pass a uri to an image. So navigate to your endpoint and then click on export map.  You can choose how to export it.  Look at this example: http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Physical_Map/MapServer/export?format=png